# How to hit an API Endpoint with a sklearn Model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, flask

I am currently stuck trying to load a model to make a prediction and load the result into an API endpoint.  I have this code, which contains the model and saves the model as a pickle file.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import pickle
from sklearn import datasets#Iris Dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data#KMeans
km = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
km.fit(X)
km.predict(X)
labels = km.labels_#Plotting
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(7,7))
ax = Axes3D(fig, rect=[0, 0, 0.95, 1], elev=48, azim=134)
ax.scatter(X[:, 3], X[:, 0], X[:, 2],
          c=labels.astype(np.float), edgecolor="k", s=50)
ax.set_xlabel("Petal width")
ax.set_ylabel("Sepal length")
ax.set_zlabel("Petal length")
plt.title("K Means", fontsize=14)

with open('C:\\Users\\ryans\\kmeans.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(km, f)
```

This seems to work fine, but the last two lines, to pickle the file and save it, seems necessary ONLY the first time it is run.  If I open the file, using the code below, I don't see the need to re-save the picked file.  Anyway, here is the code that I am testing, to hit the API endpoint.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import requests

api = Flask(__name__)
@api.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
     json_features = requests.json
     query_df = pd.DataFrame(json_features)
     features = pd.get_dummies(query_df)
     prediction = kmeans.predict(features)
     return jsonify({'prediction': list(prediction)})
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
     try:
         kmeans = pickle.load(open("C:\\Users\\ryans\\kmeans.pkl", "rb"))
         api.run(debug=True, port=8000)
         traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
     except:
        print("Exception in user code:")
        print('-'*60)
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
        print('-'*60)
```

When I run that code, I get this error.

```
 * Serving Flask app "untitled41" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with windowsapi reloader
Exception in user code:
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-48-1749e4d56106>", line 19, in <module>
    api.run(debug=True, port=8000)
  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 990, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 1050, in run_simple
    run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type)
  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\_reloader.py", line 339, in run_with_reloader
    sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
SystemExit: 1
------------------------------------------------------------
```

It's probably easier here to modify my original post with my findings, based on what you suggested.

I added this:

```
api.run(debug=True, port=8000, use_reloader=False)
```

Now, I go to my browser and enter this: 'http://localhost:8000/predict'

I see this result:

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

I tested a very simple sample script:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api', methods=['GET','POST','DELETE'])
def api():
    return 'YOU MADE IT!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000, use_reloader=False)
```

This works totally fine for me!

Finally, I don't understand this part:

```
export FLASK_APP=my_app.py
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
flask run
```

Does this go at the end of the 'kmeans.py' script?  When I add that, I get 'Invalid Syntax' on the first of the three lines.

Comment: Are you running this flask code in a notebook?

Comment: No, I'm running it in Spyder.  I noticed that there was some kind of error in 'app.py'.  I thought something may have gotten corrupt at some point, so I just uninstalled Flask and then reinstalled Flask.  I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: can you try my recommendation and let me know if it helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using the flask code in notebook (Ipython environment) and `debug=True` is forcing the process to reload, which is causing this issue, you can set use_reload to `False`

```
api.run(debug=True, port=8000, use_reloader=False)
```

Also, try to run it in a script with flask command (from command line /console) instead by first save the code in a file (for e.g app.py) and setting the script name and debug mode as below

```
export FLASK_APP=my_app.py
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
flask run
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and updated my original post with my findings.

Comment: If first part part works for you, you dnt need the second thing, its just a way to run flask by command line. Please feel free to upvote and accept it as an answer if it works

Comment: It doesn't work.  When I enter 'http://localhost:8000/predict' or 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/predict', I get this: 'Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.'.  I must be missing something simple.  It seems like it's pretty close, and I think the code pretty much makes sense, but something is still off here.

Comment: First, You main issue related to this question is solved, being an experienced stackoverflow user, you shold know that you need to create different question for different issue.
Secondly, in your code you are catching POST request and here your are send get request to /predict